# Select from second table column based on result of select from different table

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to use the result of querying one table to then use as my "where" for the 
column of a second table. This is what I've been trying:

```
SELECT channel
FROM shows
WHERE ID ='36741'
```

This gives me a result of "Discovery". All the rows of "channels" on the table "shows" are columns on the table "cccservices". I then need to do the following:

```
SELECT service
FROM cccservices
WHERE Discovery='x'
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT service
FROM cccservices
WHERE (Select channel from shows where ID='36741')='x'
```

but I'm sure I'm missing something. The ID is given to me by a user submitted form if that matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still doing my degree and I have no idea of the context of this query, but looking at your statements, wouldn't this query be better in performance?

```
SELECT service 
FROM cccservices 
INNER JOIN shows ON (ID = '36741' AND Discovery = 'x' AND ID = Discovery);
```

After you told me that and I read it another time I would go for this:

```
SELECT service 
FROM cccservices 
WHERE ((Select channel from shows where ID='36741')='x' AND Discovery ='x');
```

3rd Try:

```
SELECT service 
FROM cccservices 
WHERE ((Select channel from shows where ID='36741') = Discovery 
  AND Discovery LIKE '%x%');
```

4th TRY

```
SELECT service 
FROM cccservices 
INNER JOIN cccservices ON ((SELECT channel FROM shows INNER JOIN shows ON (ID='36741')) LIKE '%x%');
```

This returns you the column and then you want it to contain x. I think you aren't missing anything here... And your query was pretty similar!

5th Try:

```
SELECT cccs1.service 
FROM cccservices cccs1
INNER JOIN cccservices cccs2 ON ((SELECT s1.channel FROM shows s1 INNER JOIN 
shows s2 ON (ID='36741')) LIKE '%x%');
```

Comment: I don't know "Discovery" until I run the first query though. The only known value before queries is the ID

Comment: Than I would go for this:                                                                          SELECT service FROM cccservices WHERE ((Select channel from shows where ID='36741')='x' AND Discovery ='x');  
You didn't say that 'x' was "comming" from Discovery

Comment: I need to know the name of each row that contains an 'x' from the column in the table "cccservices" that I find as a result of the first query. So the first select results "discovery" then I need to know all rows in the "cccservices" table that have an "x" under the "discovery" column. Does that make more sense?

Comment: is the column Discovery a String? or just a char? if its a string an you want an x in any position u need the '%x%', check code I wrote on top.

Comment: I think Im not understanding or explaining something correctly. The first query uses the id to find what column to check for 'x's. Before the first query finishes, i have no way to know what column (discovery in my example) to use. If the ID changes, the channel changes and therefore the column changes.

Comment: Ok, here I go, My code would SELECT service when the whatever column the select of the ID gives you contains the char 'x' in the supposed String. I don't think there's anything missing in this querry and it's pretty similar to your querry, mine only uses the INNERS as I think they are better than using a WHERE.

Comment: I keep getting a syntax error that the column name is ambiguous. I thought you couldnt do inner join unless at least one column from each table shared values?

Comment: ok, try this: if it's something else I have no clue at all :(